# Toggle Button Link in html/css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I have the following code:

```js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

(function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    var banner;
    banner = document.querySelector('.exponea-banner3');
    banner.classList.add('exponea-in3');
    return banner.querySelector('.exponea-close3').addEventListener('click', function() {
      return banner.classList.remove('exponea-in3');
    });
  });

}).call(this);
});
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*=====================*/
.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.checkbox:after, .checkbox:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-feature-settings: normal;
  -webkit-font-kerning: auto;
          font-kerning: auto;
  font-language-override: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-synthesis: weight style;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
}
.checkbox label {
  width: 90px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 46px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.checkbox label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: -5px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.checkbox input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.checkbox input:hover + label:after {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 3px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  left: 40px;
}

.model-7 .checkbox label {
  background: none;
  border: 5px solid #555;
  height: 42px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.model-7 .checkbox label:after {
  background: #555;
  box-shadow: none;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
}
.model-7 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  border-color: #04c6db;
}
.model-7 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #04c6db;
  left: 50px;
}


/*banner*/
/* Banner*/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500");
html3,
body3 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.exponea-banner3 {
 
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #2e364d;
  color: #ebeef7;
  padding: 30px 80px 30px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 30px rgba(116, 119, 176, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  display: none;
}
.exponea-banner3.exponea-in3 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-close3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-label3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-text3 {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-count3 {
  font-weight: 500;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-label3 {
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner3,
.exponea-close3,
.exponea-text3,
.exponea-label3,
.exponea-label3 {
    z-index: 10;
}
.open3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="banner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>

<!-- First -->
    <div class="exponea-banner3 open3">
        <div class="exponea-close3">
            &times;
        </div>
        <div class="exponea-text3">
            Hi There! Thanks For Stumbling Upon My Website!
        </div>
<div class="exponea-count3">

Want To Switch Website View?
<div class="model-7">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <label></label>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
        <div class="exponea-label3">
            - Hussain Omer
        </div>
    </div>





<script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to add a link to the toggle button. For example, when the user clicks the button it should direct them to this link: https://noxiousdigitalclass.hussainomer.repl.co/

This is just an example, but how would I go about setting them up since the CSS is what controls the animation of the toggle button?

### Expected Output

When the user clicks the toggle button, it should direct them to this link: https://noxiousdigitalclass.hussainomer.repl.co/

Comment: Just an observation but a toggle button is really a odd visual for a what is essentially a link.

Comment: I am making it work as a dark mode/light mode functionality. There are more things that need to be added but this is just the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, when the user checks the checkbox, you want to redirect the user to an site. You’re right about the css, you will not be able to use css to redirect. An simple way to do this is by using on click events. Just replace your checkbox with this:

```
<input onclick="setTimeout(function(){location.href='https://noxiousdigitalclass.hussainomer.repl.co';}, 1000);" type="checkbox"/>
```

I’l explain the code, when you check the input, it will wait 1 second to let the animation play. Then after the second is over, it will go to the link you want it to go to.

Please tell me if this doesn’t work.

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="banner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>

<!-- First -->
    <div class="exponea-banner3 open3">
        <div class="exponea-close3">
            &times;
        </div>
        <div class="exponea-text3">
            Hi There! Thanks For Stumbling Upon My Website!
        </div>
<div class="exponea-count3">

Want To Switch Website View?
<div class="model-7">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input onclick="setTimeout(function(){location.href='https://noxiousdigitalclass.hussainomer.repl.co';}, 1000);" type="checkbox"/>
    <label></label>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
        <div class="exponea-label3">
            - Hussain Omer
        </div>
    </div>





<script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry what checkbox again? and what file?

Comment: @sidekick12 the input type=checkbox

Comment: I’ l edit my answer for the full code if you want.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! I can use that as an example then for my other banner

Comment: Why the `setTimeout` instead of just a `window.location = "www.google.com";`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, it’s becuase he has an toggle animation playing when you click it, so it waits for the animation before redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be inside the button tag you add the  tag with it and between the  tags you would put the word that shows up `<button><a href="https://noxiousdigitalclass.hussainomer.repl.co/>BUTTON</a></button>`